# Good non-commercial hardware diagnostic CD?

Tags: hardware, performance-analysis, diagnostics, repair

I fix and optimize computers for myself and my friends, so I am looking for a good Live CD that I can just pop into a computer and it will run tests of all the major hardware components in order to see if any are dying and need to be replaced.

I think a basic hardware diagnostic CD should at minimum test the following: memory, hard drives, video card, and processor.

My number one concern is that all the tests be bundled into the same program. I don't want to have to keep going back to the computer to run different tests. I want to hit start, it runs all the tests, then I come back and the tests are complete, with it telling me which ones passed and failed.

Finishing within a reasonable amount of time is also a concern. Preferably no more than 1-2 hours for a one hard drive computer.

The tests should be non-destructive. No writing to parts of the hard drive that contain files.

I am currently using a commercial CD but I would like to switch to a free program. What are some good ISO's that I could burn onto a CD and use for this?

Some promising options I've discovered from Googling and reading around the internet are stresslinux and Inquisitor. However I would like to hear what you guys use.

Comment: Inquisitor was unable to finish booting Linux. It hung up at some point in the boot process. StressLinux had a really high learning curve (you had to know all these parameters) and the tests were individual, not one program tests everything like I'm looking for. Knoppix successfully booted but it is just a Linux Live CD. It does not appear to have any hardware tests aside from some extremely rudimentary CPU benchmarks in the control panel.

Comment: Is the $300 commercial program Pc-Check the only option out there? Are there no good free options? :(